# What is this object in the water?

Tags: make-no-wonder

What is this object in [Make No Wonder](http://www.matthewhollett.com/wonder/)?

[image]

I have built a bridge to one but I can't seem to collect anything from it.

Comment: Looks like ice. I went to one on a raft and all I got was the cold condition.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann That's not a bad answer.